# Correct way to connect Instagram API

Tags: facebook, web, progressive-web-apps, instagram-api

I am trying to connect Instagram to my app. The users will not be able to use the app without connecting to Instagram, therefore I technically need Instagram auth. But Facebook states the following:

`Note that Basic Display is not an authentication tool. Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app users or log them into your app. If your app uses API data to authenticate users, it will be rejected during App Review. If you need an authentication solution, use Facebook Login instead.`

So I had to implement a Facebook login. After Facebook login is complete, I am sending the user to Instagram auth window for a second authorization which feels weird for a user.

The other solution that I can think of is the following:

Use Instagram's `user_id` that is retrieved after Instagram auth and use it to create a custom auth method with Firebase. (I believe this would be rejected at app review)

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Sources:

Instagram auth: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-authorize

Firebase custom auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

NOTE: Facebook login has "instagram_basic" scope but that doesn't allow me to get instagram info or media of normal users (non-business accounts)

Comment: Hello, how did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: Sorry for a year late answer but I did not fully solve this. I used another login method for the app and later just connected Instagram via their Basic Display and even that had to open up a browser and did not have an APK just for Instagram. At that time Facebook documentation was terribly unclear. I hope they will fix this.